# What to write instead of \x20 in path name in Bash?

Tags: command-line, paths, unicode, filename

I have an external hard drive called "My Book". When I used the command:

```
find /dev/disk/
```

it shows me that it is under

```
/dev/disk/by-label/My\x20Book
```

However, when I type in

```
find /dev/disk/ | grep My\x20Book
```

It just gives me the error

```
find: `/dev/disk/by-label/Myx20Book': No such file or directory
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
find /dev/disk/ | grep My\x20Book
find /dev/disk/ | grep My' 'Book
find /dev/disk/ | grep "My Book"
find /dev/disk/ | grep My\ Book
```

What is the correct way to enter this special character in a path name in Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the path is `My\x20Book` with the backslash, an attempt to `grep` it will have to escape the backslash both from `grep`, and from `bash`, and that can be done by using backslashes twice for each level:

```
$ echo 'My\x20Book' | grep My\\\\x20Book
My\x20Book
```

The shell reduces each `\\` to `\`, so `grep` receives `My\\x20Book`, and then grep reduces `\\` to `\`, so that it finally matches just `My\x20Book`.

To protect from the shell, you can quote the backslash, and eliminate the outer set of backslashes:

```
$ echo 'My\x20Book' | grep 'My\\x20Book'
My\x20Book
```

To protect from `grep`, you can tell it use fixed strings and not regular expressions, and now use just a single backslash:

```
$ echo 'My\x20Book' | grep -F 'My\x20Book'
My\x20Book
```

---

By the way, since you're using `find`, you can just use its filtering ability directly:

```
$ touch 'My\x20Book'
$ find . -name 'My\\x20Book'
./My\x20Book
```

Comment: Right, this is the correct answer. I did not pay attention that you use the path name as regex pattern for `grep` which requires a higher escaping level...